# sql join using partial string match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join two tables but the data elements in one of the tables have decimal and I don’t want to use the decimals when joining the 2 tables because they don’t much.  For instance, the key in the Customer table is 405.02 but in the other table it is 405.  So when joining, I only want to use everything before the period.  How would I do this?  thanks
here is my code

```
 update mytable
 set myField = 'xxx'
 from CustomerTbl
 where CustomerTbl.mainKey = mytable.mainKey
```

Comment: what datatype are the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET 
   myField = 'xxx'
FROM 
   CustomerTbl ct
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT leftKey=floor(mainKey)
    FROM mytable
) as upd on upd.leftKey = ct.mainKey
```

Floor() function if available should give you the left-hand side of the decimal for joining.

Answer (score 2):

If your field is varchar, you can use this:

```
SUBSTRING(CustomerTbl.mainKey, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CustomerTbl.mainKey))
```

If it is an decimal/float, you must convert it first:

```
SUBSTRING(CAST(CustomerTbl.mainKey AS VARCHAR(10)), 0, CHARINDEX('.', CAST(CustomerTbl.mainKey AS VARCHAR(10))))
```

You will also need to then CAST `mytable.mainKey` in your WHERE clause.

EDIT: [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac3e9/7)

```
update mytable
 set myField = 'xxx'
 from CustomerTbl
 where SUBSTRING(CAST(CustomerTbl.mainKey AS VARCHAR(20)), 0, CHARINDEX('.', CAST(CustomerTbl.mainKey AS VARCHAR(20)))) = CAST(mytable.mainKey AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: How could an int have "stuff after the ."?  It must be a numeric of some type which is not int.

Comment: Total brain fart on that one, thank you. I fixed my answer. The `SUBSTRING` should still be fine.

Comment: +1 You should point out the pain possible here -- parameter sniffing issues and lack of index use could make this kind of join VERY SLOW!